# I am trying to scroll to the same position in recyclerview when the device is rotated - although the position gets saved does not get displayed right

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview, restore

I am trying to scroll to the same position in my Recyclerview when a user rotates the device. I am saving the Position here:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int index = llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();//llm is my layoutmanager
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Pos", index);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And restore it here:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mPosRev = savedInstanceState.getInt("Pos");
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: "+mPosRev);
    llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mPosRev,10);
}
```

I can see by the logs, that the Position is stored correctly, but not scrolled to. I already tried smoothScrollToPosition as well as scrollToPosition.

This is my Adapter

```
private final Review mLock = new Review();

private List<Review> mObjects;
public ReviewAdapter( List<Review> objects) {
    mObjects = objects;
}


public void add(Review object) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mObjects.add(object);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void add(ReviewDetail object) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "add: "+object.getContent());
            mObjects.add(new Review(object));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        mObjects.clear();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ReviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
    Context context=viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem=R.layout.item_movie_review;
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view=inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, false);
    ReviewViewHolder viewHolder= new ReviewViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ReviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (null == mObjects) return 0;
    return mObjects.size();
}

class ReviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Author;
    TextView Txt;

    public ReviewViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        Txt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }

    void bind(int listIndex) {
        Author.setText(mObjects.get(listIndex).getAuthor());
        Txt.setText(mObjects.get(listIndex).getContent());
    }
}
```

}

And in here I initalize my Recyclerview:

```
recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    mReviewAdapter = new ReviewAdapter(new ArrayList<Review>());
    recList.setAdapter(mReviewAdapter);
```

Any ideas on what could cause this behavior?